# Why does switching the architecture result in nans during training?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, train

What are my options to figure out the casue of spontaneous nans/infs during training?
Basically I changed the model from a custom resnet to the vanilla resnet(and also later a vggnet varation) and then out of nowhere I'm getting nans, 3, 4 iterations into the training.
I found out the nans are caused by the second module which is `ArcFaceMargin` implemented like this :

```py
class ArcMarginModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, args):
        super(ArcMarginModel, self).__init__()

        self.weight = Parameter(torch.FloatTensor(num_classes, args.emb_size))
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.weight)

        self.easy_margin = args.easy_margin
        self.m = args.margin_m
        self.s = args.margin_s

        self.cos_m = math.cos(self.m)
        self.sin_m = math.sin(self.m)
        self.th = math.cos(math.pi - self.m)
        self.mm = math.sin(math.pi - self.m) * self.m

    def forward(self, input, label):
        x = F.normalize(input)
        W = F.normalize(self.weight)
        cosine = F.linear(x, W)
        sine = torch.sqrt(1.0 - torch.pow(cosine, 2))
        phi = cosine * self.cos_m - sine * self.sin_m  # cos(theta + m)
        if self.easy_margin:
            phi = torch.where(cosine > 0, phi, cosine)
        else:
            phi = torch.where(cosine > self.th, phi, cosine - self.mm)
        one_hot = torch.zeros(cosine.size(), device=device)
        one_hot.scatter_(1, label.view(-1, 1).long(), 1)
        output = (one_hot * phi) + ((1.0 - one_hot) * cosine)
        output *= self.s
        return output
```

In the default configuration, the optimizer uses the same learning rate of `0.1` for both modules, that is the base resnet18 and the arcface module and it works just fine.

```py
...
# custom resnet18
model = resnet18(args)
metric_fc = ArcMarginModel(args)

if args.optimizer == 'sgd':
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD([{'params': model.parameters()}, 
                                 {'params': metric_fc.parameters()}],
                                lr=0.1, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.0005)
```

However, with any other base models, after couple of iterations(and I mean like 3~6 interations), the loss becomes all nans and infs.
The only way I can get this to work with other architectures e.g. vanialla resnet18, is to use a much lower learning rate for the `ArchMarginModel` (i.e. `metric_fc`).
Basically what worked for me so far is the `lr=0.1` for the base model and `0.001` for the `metric_fc`.

```py
model = resnet18(args)
metric_fc = ArcMarginModel(args)

if args.optimizer == 'sgd':
    optim_sgd = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.0005)
    optim_sgd.add_param_group({'params': metric_fc.parameters(), "lr":0.001 })
```

This is not optimal in any way and I have no idea why this is the case, and how I can get the same behavior of the custom model.
For the reference this is the custom resnet 18 model : [github.com/insigntfacev2/models.py](https://github.com/foamliu/InsightFace-v2/blob/master/models.py#L223)

The `SE` block is set false, so what remains is basically nearly the vanilla resnet ([torchvision.models.py] except that in the custom resnet the `BasicBlock`, has a batchnorm in the begining of the `forward()` and in the `ResNet` forward() there are two batchnorms at the end.

Also note that I also have replaced all `PReLU()`s with `ReLU()`s, to further make it closer to the vanilla resnet yet the custom one works with the same learning rate, while the vanila resnet needs **100x** lower learning rate for the second module to work!

Having all this said, Why do I see this behavior in different models?
I'm looking for figuring out the underlying issue.
Why does the base model, affect the second module this much? what is it that the custom model seems to be having while the others dont?

### Note:

I was scheptical as whether to ask this on stackoverflow or here, but since I dont think its code centric, I prefered to ask it here.
Please note that this question is not about the programming aspect, this is about the underlying issue and its causes.

The code snippets posted below are just to provide some background/referrence that might be useful.
if You think thi still needs to be migrated to Stackoverflow or is indeed involves coding related issues pelase kindly do so.

Comment: it's not clear to me that argument passed to `torch.sqrt(1.0 - torch.pow(cosine, 2))` is strictly positive, that's probably the source of your nans

Comment: @shimao thanks, but thats not the issue, I just found the vanilla models return `nan`s. I checked and the inputs are fine. but its the models that actually produce nan!

Comment: i still think it's likely the source of the problem is your loss. Even if the vanilla models are perfectly fine, any nan in the loss will backpropagate and cause the model weights to become nan, which will make it seem like the nan is coming from the model (even though the original cause is the loss), so it's very tricky to trace the "root cause" of the nan.

Comment: oh I see, yes you have a point there thanks a lot. I'll make sure to check the loss in depth. so to reiterate, you think the nan is actually being made in the loss and during backprop it ruins everything. so the grads starting from the loss should be nan to indicate this right? and if this is indeed the case, what part of the loss should I be meddling with? the `W`'s norm? grad? rally appreciate your kind help and insight. its invaluable to me.

Comment: First to check that the square root is really the cause, I suggest clipping the expression inside to be *strictly* positive, for example, `torch.sqrt(torch.clamp(1.0 - torch.pow(cosine, 2), min=1E-6))`. (non-negative is not enough, must be strictly positive). That should tell you for sure if it's causing problems, or if it's something else. As I don't really know what your loss is trying to accomplish, I can't provide advice for the "right way" to implement it, although that might be a fair topic for a separate question.

Comment: Thanks a lot @shimao really appreciate it.I'll look into and report back

Comment: @shimao, thanks a lot. doing that indeed stoped the nans for good! However, I noticed doing so also stops  the network from learning! the loss decreases, but the network doesnt learn anything and the acc is always 50.0% in all epochs. this is indeed very weird to me, never seen this behavior before. making eps lower (1e-9) and lowering the lr, resulted in a better acc (51.66), but this seems to be making it really hard for the network to actually learn something. at least this seems to me. not sure if this is the right conclusion though

Comment: yes, clipping the loss will mess with the gradients -- it's just a quick way to check where the nans are coming from. since i don't know what your loss is trying to do, i can't advise on the right way to implement it